# 2D ArrayLoops C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Having trouble getting my code to run properly, first time I have ever used C++ and just trying to learn it for my knowledge, I am trying to get a 2d array with all zeros except in the final column. Inputs are stock = 100, strike = 100, time to maturity = 1, interest rate = 0.06, time steps = 3, upfactor = 1.1, downfactor = 0.9091. The end Array should look like {[0,0,0,133.10], [0,0,0,110], [0,0,0,90.91], [0,0,0,75.13]}, bot for some reason I keep getting values in the first column as well and I am stumped. Any advice?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char*pszArgs[])
{
double st;
cout << " Enter Value of stock: ";
cin >> st;

double K;
cout << " Enter Value of strike price: ";
cin >> K;

double t;
cout << " Enter time of maturity: ";
cin >> t;

double r;
cout << " Enter Value of the interest rate: ";
cin >> r;

int N;
cout << " Enter Value of time steps: ";
cin >> N;

double u;
cout << " Enter value of up factor: ";
cin >> u;

double d;
cout << " Enter Value of down factor: ";
cin >> d;

double dt;
dt = t/N;

double p;
p = (exp(r*dt)-d)/(u-d);

// Initialise asset price at maturity time step N
double price[N][N];

for( int i = 0; i < N+1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<N+1; j++)
    {
       price[i][j] = 0;
   }
}

price[N][N] = st*pow(d,N);
cout << "price[N][N] is equal to: " << price[N][N] << endl;

double newN;
newN = N-1;

//cout << price[2][0] << endl;

for(int ii = newN; ii >=0; ii--)
{
price[ii][N] = (price[ii+1][N]) * (u/d);
}

//cout << price[2][0] << endl;

for( int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <=N; j++)
    {
       cout << price[i][j] << "  ";
   }
       cout << endl;
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;

}
```

The problem area is

```
for(int ii = newN; ii >=0; ii--)
{
price[ii][N] = (price[ii+1][N]) * (u/d);
}
```

and not sure exactly how to fix it. Any thoughts??

Comment: change `double newN;` to `int newN;`. change `i < N+1` to `i < N`. change `i <= N` to `i < N` (the same for j)

Comment: `price[ii+1][N]` also wrong...

Comment: Please consider learning basic array handling in C++ before asking. This is a very simple question and has been answered dozen of times in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ indexes are from 0

```
double price[N][N];
```

or

```
double price[10][10];
```

means that you have an array from 0..9 and 0..9

so

```
price[N][N] = st*pow(d,N);
```

is writing to a location outside the arrays as the maximum index is `price[N-1][N-1]`

and for that reason, loops in C/C++

```
for( int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
```

should be written as

```
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++)
```

since N is not included as a valid index value for the array.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues with your program.
You have created a double dimensional array on stack with variable sized length (N).
If your array size is dynamic don't create it on stack, use new to allocate it on heap.
Also, as I see it you are accessing out-of-array entries. (Index greater than max array index)